# Previous item search in apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm quite new to big data area and I'm going to solve a problem. I am currently gauging the Spark solution and would like to check if this could be achieved by Spark.

My simplified input data schema:

```
|TransactionID|CustomerID|Timestamp|
```

What I'd like to get is for each transaction ID, find the 5 previous transaction IDs within the same customer. So the output data schema would look like:

```
|TransactionID|1stPrevTID|2ndPrevTID|...|5thPrevTID|
```

My input data source is around billion entries.

Here my question would be, is Spark a good candidate for solution or should I consider something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the `lag` function.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lag
from pyspark.sql import Window
#Assuming the dataframe is named df
w = Window.partitionBy(df.customerid).orderBy(df.timestamp)
df_with_lag = df.withColumn('t1_prev',lag(df.transactionID,1).over(w))\
                .withColumn('t2_prev',lag(df.transactionID,2).over(w))\
                .withColumn('t3_prev',lag(df.transactionID,3).over(w))\
                .withColumn('t4_prev',lag(df.transactionID,4).over(w))\
                .withColumn('t5_prev',lag(df.transactionID,5).over(w))
df_with_lag.show()
```

[**`Documentation on lag`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lag)

> Window function: returns the value that is offset rows before the current row, and defaultValue if there is less than offset rows before the current row. For example, an offset of one will return the previous row at any given point in the window partition.